# Application wide variable (not a constant) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, global-variables

There are many answers for questions how to make app-wide variables in Rails, but all of them describe rather config parameters than real variables.

So, my question is:

How to make an application-wide variable which could be set in one method of one controller and read in other method of other controller, in other session, several minutes later?

Comment: store in the database?

Comment: @emaillenin: This variable is meant for not querying database too often. It should be a trigger "database has new data for you - query it".

Comment: Database + cache should work well for you. What about redis?

Comment: the problem with variables being used across sessions is that you lose control over them. you never know which session/user/request is modifying the variables.

Comment: @emaillenin: it isn't important in my case who modified data.

Comment: From the above it sounds like Rails caching is what you really need: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html